# d3js: how to bind data within a single object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a bar chart using a single object. I isolated this object from the larger dataset, but now am having trouble using `.data`  on it. It seems the only format in which `.bind` will work would be several objects within an array. My project is made so that when a user clicks on a certain date, it grabs the object from the dataset and creates the corresponding bar graph. Would `bind` work in this context?

```
Object {Date: "2010", Paper and Paperboard: "71310", Glass: "11520", Ferrous: "16920", Aluminum: "3510"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D3, the `data()` function accepts three things:

1. An array
2. A function
3. Nothing

That being said, if you have just a single object, you have to wrap it in an array:

```
var myData = [{Date: "2010", Paper and Paperboard: "71310", Glass: "11520", Ferrous: "16920", Aluminum: "3510"}];
```

And then:

```
data(myData)
```

Or, alternatively:

```
var myObject = {Date: "2010", Paper and Paperboard: "71310", Glass: "11520", Ferrous: "16920", Aluminum: "3510"};

data([myObject])
```

But you'll have **only one element** in your enter selection.

A better approach would be iterating over that object to create an array of objects.

PS: We all know that in JavaScript *arrays are objects*, but I believe my point here is clear: the `data()` function accepts an *specific type of object*, which we call an *array*.

Comment: Thanks again, I was hoping that d3 could treat my object as multiple data entries. I will try creating an array of Objects

Comment: Yes, try this, it's certainly the best approach.